# Where is the client validation library?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am coding for sharepoint 2010.  according to this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside), When you view page source for the browser, you should find something like this in order to use validation library. I did not find it.

```
<script language="javascript" 
        src="/aspnet_client/system_web/1_0_3617_0/WebUIValidation.js">
</script>
```

I am confused, can you explain how validation library is loaded to client browser.

Answer (score 1):

The `WebUIValidation.js` file contains client-side JavaScript functions for client-side validation. It is *automatically* injected into a page when:

- The page contains one or more validation Web controls.
- The page is being visited by an “uplevel” browser.

I fired up Reflector to sneek a peak at the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator` class, which is the class from which all validation Web controls are derived. The `RegisterValidationCommonScript()` method  is responsible.

Credits to: http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2004/11/03/163009.aspx

Reflected via ILSpy (.NET 4.0):

```
// System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator
protected void RegisterValidatorCommonScript()
{
    if (this.Page.IsPartialRenderingSupported)
    {
        ValidatorCompatibilityHelper.RegisterClientScriptResource(this, typeof(BaseValidator), "WebUIValidation.js");
        ValidatorCompatibilityHelper.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(BaseValidator), "ValidatorIncludeScript", "\r\nvar Page_ValidationActive = false;\r\nif (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == \"function\") {\r\n    ValidatorOnLoad();\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction ValidatorOnSubmit() {\r\n    if (Page_ValidationActive) {\r\n        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();\r\n    }\r\n    else {\r\n        return true;\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n        ", true);
        ValidatorCompatibilityHelper.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, typeof(BaseValidator), "ValidatorOnSubmit", "if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == \"function\" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;");
        return;
    }
    if (this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(typeof(BaseValidator), "ValidatorIncludeScript"))
    {
        return;
    }
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(BaseValidator), "WebUIValidation.js");
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(BaseValidator), "ValidatorIncludeScript", "\r\nvar Page_ValidationActive = false;\r\nif (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == \"function\") {\r\n    ValidatorOnLoad();\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction ValidatorOnSubmit() {\r\n    if (Page_ValidationActive) {\r\n        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();\r\n    }\r\n    else {\r\n        return true;\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n        ", true);
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(BaseValidator), "ValidatorOnSubmit", "if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == \"function\" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;");
}
```